# Склонение фамилии Филык

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилия Филык? Носитель этой фамилии (мужчина) утверждает, что не склоняется.

Comment: Если мужчина - я бы склонял. Но это мое субъективное мнение.

Answer (score 1):

> **4.** Если фамилия оканчивается на согласный (кроме фамилий на *-ых, -их*...), то здесь — и только здесь! — имеет значение пол носителя фамилии. **Все мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, склоняются — это закон русской грамматики.** Все женские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, не склоняются. При этом языковое происхождение фамилии не имеет значения. Склоняются в том числе и мужские фамилии, совпадающие с нарицательными существительными.
>
> Примеры: *тетрадь Михаила Бока, дипломы выданы Александру Кругу и Константину Королю, встреча с Игорем Шипелевичем, в гостях у Андрея Мартынюка, дочь Ильи Скалозуба, работа Исаака Акопяна...*

*Сендык, Крик, Катык, Брик, Кулик, Калмык* — вот похожие фамилии, которые, если принадлежат мужчине, склоняются.

Из статей:
*Она снималась в картинах Егора Кончаловского, Сергея **Сендыка**, Владимира Зайкина, Алексея Голубева, Петра Кротенка и многих других;

Жизнь и творчество Федора **Калмыка** является примером служения Отечеству.*

*Сатирические и юмористические произведения в литературном наследии караимского писателя и поэта Арона Ильича **Катыка*** (1883–1942) — статья Д. А. Прохорова.

[Склонение фамилий](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/)

Answer (score 0):

Склоняется. все мужские фамилии должны склоняться, когда оканчиваются на согласную.

Comment: не совсем. На -ых/-их не склоняются.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, нормативно фамилия должна склоняться.

> 13.1.3. Фамилии с показателями -ов- и -ин- имеют в мужском роде особое склонение, не встречающееся ни среди личных имен, ни среди
>   нарицательных существительных. В нем объединены окончания
>   существительных второго склонения мужского рода и прилагательных типа
>   отцов. От склонения указанных существительных склонение фамилий
>   отличается окончанием творительного падежа (ср.: Кольцов-ым,
>   Никитин-ым — остров-ом, кувшин-ом), от склонения притяжательных
>   прилагательных — окончанием предложного падежа (ср.: о Грибоедов-е, о
>   Карамзин-е — об отцов-ом, о мамин-ом).
>
> ...
>
> То же надо сказать о склонении фамилий на -ов и -ин во множественном
>   числе (Базаровы, Рудины склоняются как отцовы, мамины).
>
> 13.1.4. Все прочие мужские фамилии, имеющие основы на согласные и нулевое окончание в именительном падеже (на письме они кончаются
>   согласной буквой, ь или й), кроме фамилий на -ых, -их, склоняются как
>   существительные второго склонения мужского рода, т. е. имеют в
>   творительном падеже окончание -ом, (-ем): Герценом, Левитаном,
>   Гоголем, Врубелем, Хемингуэем, Гайдаем. Такие фамилии воспринимаются
>   как «нерусские».

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482

Есть единичные исключения (в основном - фонетического порядка: связанные c неблагозвучием или труднопроизносимостью), когда носитель может претендовать на изменение **типа** склонения, но о полной несклоняемости речи не идет.

Фамилия Филык должна склоняться по общим правилам (как "балык", "кадык" и "таджик"). И это вне зависимости от места ударения.

Comment: У меня есть знакомая, у которой девичья фамилия Балюк, что очень созвучно с "балыком".)) Так вот я спросил у неё, и она говорит, что фамилию мужчин в их семье не склоняют. Что, однако, может говорить и о неправильной привычке, сложившейся у них без особых к тому оснований.